# Ignoring irrelevant resource bundles in IntelliJ IDEA autocomplete

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, intellij-idea

When editing JSF XHTML files and using autocomplete for resource bundle keys, IntelliJ seems to scan the whole project including libraries for ALL property files - this is very annoying because you get many thousands of irrelevant keys mixed up with your own small JSF declared resource bundle. Is it possible to ignore library property files? This was default behaviour in Netbeans for example, one of the things that really annoys me in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to control it in the current IDEA version (12), all the files are always scanned. Please [submit a request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) to make it configurable and we'll consider implementing it in the future updates.